# Windows 8 Powershell Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature bat file

Tags: iis, powershell, windows-8, batch-file

I have a .bat file that runs a powershell script. This is it

```
powershell -Command "& {Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole}"
```

I have done this before and if I wanted to add another command I would put a semicolon before the closing brace and continue the script.

This command however after completed requires that I choose wheter or not to restart the computer with a Y or N.

[image]

Does anyone know how to pass this in an argument or avoid this step all together?

Thanks in advance

Note: you have to run the .bat file as adminstrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `Get-Help Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Full`:

```
 -NoRestart [<SwitchParameter>]
     Suppresses reboot. If a reboot is not required, this command does nothing. This option will keep the
     application from prompting for a restart or keep it from restarting automatically.
```

Add the `-NoRestart` flag to `Enable-WindowsOptionFeature` to suppress the reboot. If you *do* want to reboot after completion, use the command `Restart-Computer`.