# How to enable Hyper-V with Windows PowerShell?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I tried this command:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All
```

But, it will give me this feedback message:

```
'Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Used this as help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859979/windows-8-powershell-enable-windowsoptionalfeature-bat-file

Answer (score 4):

Try DISM instead:
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /All /FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V

See more installation information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_install).

Comment: Thanks, Sarah. Only solution that worked for me. 99% of other solutions ask you to turn it on in BIOS or turn on in "Turn on Windows features on/off", but running this command in Powershell is the only thing that enabled hyper-v back on for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already found the answer, but I write it for next generation) Just run powershell console as Administrator. I am not archaeologist, I was just looking for string for enabling hyper-v.